# Rails model - insert a record - Ruby way

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am very new to Rails 4. I have created following view

**contact_us.html.erb**

```
<%= form_tag({controller: "pages", action: "contact_us"}, method: "post", class: "nifty_form") do %>
<b> Add Product </b>
<br>
  <p>
    <%= label_tag  'Cname:' %>
    <%= text_field_tag 'cname', @cname %>
    <br>
    <%= label_tag  'Cdetail:' %>
    <%= text_field_tag 'cdetais', @cdetais %>
    <% #email_field_tag 'pdetail', @pdetail %>
  </p>
  <%= submit_tag "Save" %>
<% end %>
```

**Model : contactu.rb**

```
class Contactu < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

**pages_controller.rb**

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end

  def contact_us
    flash.now[:error] = ""

    if params[:commit]
      @cname=params[:cname]
      @cdetais=params[:cdetais]

      flash.now[:error] << "Pname cannot be blank<br/>" if @cname.nil? || @cname.empty?
      flash.now[:error] << "Cdetais cannot be blank<br/>" if @cdetais.nil? || @cdetais.empty?
    end

    Contactu.create(cname: @cname, cdetais: @cdetais)
  end
end
```

This code works. But, I was wondering is there a better way?

I have changed the code, but now it says 
undefined method `join' for #

```
@contact_us = Contactu.create(cname: @cname, cdetais: @cdetais)

    if @contact_us.save
    flash.now[:notice] << "Information saved </br>"
    else
    flash.now[:error] = @contact_us.errors.join('<br>')
    end
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course there is better way.

Firstly check if given fields are present in model:

```
class Contactu < ActiveRecord::Base
  validate :cname, presence: true
  validate :cdetails, presence: true
end
```

And then in your controller:

```
@message = Contactu.create(params.permit(:cname, :cdetails))

if @message.save
  redirect_to blah, notice: "Thank's for the news"
else
  flash[:error] = @message.errors.to_a.join('<br>')
end
```

Comment: Hi, I have changed the code. Now it is saying "undefined method `join' for .." any idea, how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I would probably create a new controller and route to contact.

```
ContactController

def index
...
def create
# on success go to index
```

Routes:

```
Resources contact, only: [:index, :create]
```

Form: use the path helpers:

```
form_for **contact_path** ...
```

If you want the link to be a part of /pages, then that could be done as well with the routes file.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, see:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#saving-data-in-the-controller

but better still, RTFM, start from the beginning of the tutorial ;-)

```
def create
  @article = Article.new(params[:article])

  @article.save
  redirect_to @article
end
```