# Rails MVC concept - model is inside controller - am I right?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have PHP background and used Codeigniter MVC framework. In Codeigniter, I have not seen any SQL manipulation in controller. Everything was in the model. I know it requires more code but model contains all SQL logic in CI.

I am not sure why Rails does it in the controller? Model only get used for validation. Am I missing something ?

Reference

In my previous post-

[Rails model - insert a record - Ruby way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32425111/rails-model-insert-a-record-ruby-way)

I have to write the create statement inside controller. Why ?!

Contactu.create(cname: @cname, cdetais: @cdetais)

Comment: The `create` statement is in the controller because the controller determines that a record needs to be created based on the user's request.  However, the create method is a class method of the model... `Contactu.create` so it is model based.  ActiveRecord defines those methods for you... `create` and `save` and `find` and `find_by`... but they are all model methods.

Comment: :create in a controller is handled by the controller and its behavior "rolls up" to ActionController. :create on a model object rolls up to ActiveRecord. They're different methods.

Comment: You should make validations at model, your controller should be really thin. I was using Codeigniter for two years and it is very easy to use Fat Controllers in Codeigniter. But not in Rails