# Changing Rails Active record column name 's error message

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have created following page

[Rails model - insert a record - Ruby way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32425111/rails-model-insert-a-record-ruby-way/32426282#32426282)

My issue is, the error message is not user friendly.
It says "Cname can't be blank " 
cname is the column name. Instead of cname I want to show "column name cannot be 
blank"
How do I do that ? Hope it is clear.

**As dimakura suggested**

```
class Contactu < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates :cname, presence: { message: 'Column name cannot be blank'}
end
```

.

```
Cname Column name cannot be blank
Cname can't be blank
```

.
In view

```
 @contact_us.errors.messages.values.each do |error| %>
    <li><b><%= error %></b></li>
  <% end %>
```

.
It is fixed now. Thanks a lot.

Thanks Guilherme Moretti. Really appreciate your help :)

Comment: You have 2 validations! Remove the second one

Comment: Still it prints "Cname Column name cannot be blank "

Comment: Do you use `model.errors.full_messages`?

Comment: yes I did. There is also  flash[:error] = 'Database Error:'+ @contact_us.errors.to_a.join('<br>') that shows the same thing.

Comment: use `@contact_us.errors.full_messages.join('<br>')` instead

Comment: Hi, I am going to remove that as view already shows the error message,.Updated my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change it like this:

```
class Contactu < ActiveRecord::Base
  validate :cname, presence: { message: 'user-friendly message' }
  validate :cdetails, presence: true
end
```

In order to hide field names, also use the following code to display your error messages:

```
model.errors.full_messages.join('<br>')
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for reply. Now it shows two errors and still prints the 'canme'.

Answer (score 4):

Errors in rails use I18n texts to generate the messages. You can set the name of the attribute in `config/locales/en.yml`

```
en:
  activerecord:
    models:
      contact: contactu 
      attributes:
      contact:
        cname: "Column name"
```

Just change to the name of model and attributes you want.

You can read more about translations in rails here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html

Comment: I have updated my post. If I add that, I got "I18n::InvalidLocaleData in PagesController#contact_us ".

Comment: Your en.yml is invalid. Below the `models:` line change to this: `contact: contactu`. And below the line `attributes` change to `contact:`

Comment: YML is very strict with the identation. Try to validate your yml file using this site http://wiki.ess3.net/yaml

Comment: YML error is gone. Not sure why. However, now it back to old issue. Now it is showing  "Cname can't be blank" instead of "coloum name cannot be blank" Updated my post.